# How to transform DF into Time Series object

Tags: r

I am a beginner trying to learn Time Series Forecasting. I am trying to plot using "Sales of Shampoo Over a Three Year Period"
Topic 12 hours ago in Getting Started

Unable to transform the data frame into the TS file. Besides the unable to make the Month into an acceptable Date format  Please help

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = 1;
 sales.of.shampoo.over.a.three.ye <- read.csv("~/sales-of-shampoo-over-a-three-ye.csv")

>   View(sales.of.shampoo.over.a.three.ye)
> library(forecast)
This is forecast 8.7 
  Need help getting started? Try the online textbook FPP:
  http://OTexts.org/fpp2/
> autoplot(sales.of.shampoo.over.a.three.ye)
Error: Objects of type data.frame not supported by autoplot.
> library(txt)
Error in library(txt) : there is no package called ‘txt’
> library(xts)
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package: base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> SH<-as.xts(sales.of.shampoo.over.a.three.ye)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Wish to proceed further and draw plots.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example please? For example a sample of your data via `dput()`.

Comment: The `as.xts` error suggest that `order.by` variable is not in the Datetime format.  You can use `as.POSIXct` with the format of the date column